# Azure Notification Hubs still reliant on GCM with 6 months to switch-off

Tags: android, azure, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub

Google have deprecated GCM for delivering push notifications to Android apps, in favour of FCM. GCM will be switched off on April 11 2019 (See header here: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm)

Microsoft have provided a tutorial for setting up a new app with Azure Notification Hubs using FCM, however it still depends on the underlying GCM library (`com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:12.0.0`):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-android-push-notification-google-fcm-get-started

With just 6 months until GCM switch off, my questions are therefore:

- Will Azure Notification Hubs Android SDK be updated to remove the dependency on `com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.8.0`?
- Will a GCM to FCM migration guide be written for existing apps using Azure Notification Hubs on Android?
- Currently the Android Azure Notification Hubs SDK relies on a deprecated `net.http.AndroidHttpClient`, which has been totally removed in Android Pie. When will this be fixed?
- What server side changes, if any, will be required to migrate from GCM to FCM when using Azure Notification Hubs?

Comment: Work is underway in this fork to migrate from `AndroidHttpClient` to `OkHttp`: https://github.com/minyushov/azure-notificationhubs/commits/master

Comment: Hi Andrew. Although your post is a pressing concern, I believe this *off-topic* here in Stack Overflow and too broad to answer.

Comment: I was actually asked to post here by @azuresupport and I would be grateful if you could not close the question - their support team is supposed to be answering here.

Comment: Hi Andrew. I've retracted my close vote. I still believe that this is off-topic -- odd that Azure would use this as a channel. However, this instance is different. I hope they do respond to you here. Good luck. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your consideration and understanding - I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure Notification Hubs team updated the SDK to address the issues you identified and also published this blog post describing the state of the GCM/FCM world as it relates to Azure Notification Hubs: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/blog/azure-notification-hubs-and-google-s-firebase-cloud-messaging-migration/ to address customer concerns.

No server-side changes needed.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond John - much appreciated.